# Stormpath token based authentication in web app

Tags: django, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, stormpath

I have a web app which is using stormpath identity management service.

Stormpath is new to me.. till now what i understood is you can signup and login into stormpath and stormpath will give you the access token. each account is associate with an application_id. right?

I read these two articles

http://docs.stormpath.com/guides/token-management/

https://stormpath.com/blog/build-api-restify-stormpath/

so here I'm having couple of questions for my use case/scenario.
here are 3 main components.

1) stormpath

2) a web app (lets call it WA1) which is using stormpath to authenticate(this app is working fine)

3) another web app(lets call it WA2) which will be using the stormpath login(for same aplicationid) and another API exposed by above webapp(WA1).

If I login in my application(WA2), I get a token. now how can I use this token to access api exposed by WA1.

what if I logout from stormpath directly, will I still be logged in in my app.
if yes then how we are authenticating user after that.

These queries might sound dumb but trust me I read and read but couldn't understand the flow. would be great if you could explain it.

PS: I'm using Django + django-stormpath (in WA1)
and angular/Node/express (in WA2)
PPS: or is it session based authentication overall(after 1st login)?

Answer (score 2):

I work at [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com) and I should be able to help.  Our framework integrations (Django, Express) will use the Stormpath API to create access and refresh tokens for the user when they log in, these are stored in Http-Only cookies, inaccassible from JavaScript.  If your two web applications are on the same root domain, you may be able to share the cookies between the applications.  If the applications are not on the same domain, you have two options:

- Use our [ID Site feature](https://docs.stormpath.com/guides/using-id-site/), to maintain a single-sign-on cookie between the two applications on different domains.
- Use the `/oauth/token` endpoint [that our framework integrations provide](http://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/latest/authentication.html#oauth2-password-grant), to get the tokens manually and then store them in local storage, in a way that allows you to use them in a cross-domain fashion.  Note: local storage does have security vulnerabilities, particularly XSS vulnerability.

I hope this answer helps!  You can also contact us via support@stormpath.com.